# where is full python3 documentation located?

Tags: python-3.x, list, insert

For lists, there is a method called insert().  Where is the documentation that tells you what happens if you try to insert an item well past the end of the list?

For example:

```
x=[]
x.insert(5,10)
```

this works and places the 10 at index 0.  Where is the documentation for this?
This sorry excuse for documentation doesn't cut it:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/list.html?highlight=insert#c.PyList_Insert

Comment: Or source code: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c

Comment: IKR. I use a few languages daily, and of all of them I find Python's documentation to be **the worst**. Takes too many steps/searches to find what you want.

Comment: totally agree haha...

Comment: @SyndRain thanks but those links are totally useless

Comment: The first link is just to show that you can see the implementation of list.insert from PyList_Insert. Next, you can see from the source code of PyList_Insert that it will resize then insert at the last index if i is greater than n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is any python documentation specifying this behavior.

However, if you dig into its implementation, you can see it will resize the list to its original size + 1, and **if the inserted location is larger than the last index, it will be placed at the last index**. (Similarly, if the inserted location is smaller than 0, it will be placed at the first index.)

In the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/list.html?highlight=insert#c.PyList_Insert) you can see `PyList_Insert` can represent the implementation of `list.insert(index, item)`, which is:

```c
PyList_Insert(PyObject *op, Py_ssize_t where, PyObject *newitem)
{
    if (!PyList_Check(op)) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return -1;
    }
    return ins1((PyListObject *)op, where, newitem);
}
```

The [source code of ins1((PyListObject *)op, where, newitem)](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c) shows that it will resize the list to size n+1 (which is 0+1=1 in your case), and the inserted location `where` will be set to index `n` (which is 0 in your case). This is why `insert(5, 10)` on `[]` will result in `[10]`.

```c
ins1(PyListObject *self, Py_ssize_t where, PyObject *v)
{
    Py_ssize_t i, n = Py_SIZE(self);
    PyObject **items;
    if (v == NULL) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return -1;
    }

    assert((size_t)n + 1 < PY_SSIZE_T_MAX);
    if (list_resize(self, n+1) < 0) /*resize from 0 to 1*/
        return -1;

    if (where < 0) {
        where += n;
        if (where < 0)
            where = 0;
    }
    if (where > n)  /*set where=0*/
        where = n;
    items = self->ob_item;
    for (i = n; --i >= where; )
        items[i+1] = items[i];
    items[where] = Py_NewRef(v);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but still not very helpful